# I have problems when trying to install Labelme

Tags: python, image-processing, anaconda

I 'm trying to work with labelme application to label my database. The location of the app is in https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme. I followed all the steps with anaconda but I had a problem when trying to open it.
[This a snapshot of the error I get when trying to open labelme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwvdW.png)
[This the rest of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HmYt.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post pictures of text, [here is, why](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). You can [edit] your question to include the error message as text.

Comment: try pip install --upgrade numpy, see if that fixes your problem

Comment: I 've tried pip install --upgrade numpy but it's still the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem when installing labelme. It tries to install imgviz which gives me errors.